Duende IdentityServer: get authorization_endpoint internally without making http call to discovery document?
I have a tiny side app hosted within my ID service. I want the user of the side app to be redirected to the authorization endpoint if they're not logged in. Is there some library API inside IdentityServer to directly get the address of the endpoint without having to submit a http request to the discovery document?
I'm familiar with using IIdentityServerTools and IIdentityServerInteractionService internally but they don't seem to satisfy this particular need.
